# Windows 7: How can I detect, whether the Firefox Browser is "Infected" by A Crypto miner or not?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, virus, bitcoin

My Parents own since a couple of years a Computer with Windows 7, and everything worked fine, until about three or nine months ago. That's when their PC started to lag! I recognized it, but didn't know what the exact Problem was. Now I know about all this bitcoin etc.! And I read some articles about those viral Crypto miners  appearing on some Websites that are persistent.

I already looked Into the taskmanager, resource monitor etc. and I found raised activity, about 20 per cent CPU usage above the normal level. Yes, I closed All Apps and background tasks like steam etc.! RAM usage is also Raised about 1.5 GB. Besides, the network activity shows about average 55% all filled with the Firefox PID 3280, although it's closed. The IP addresses they're communicating with aren' t `XxX.XxX.XxX.XxX` but Like mac adresses `Xx:xX:Xx:xX`.

So, I think it **could** be a crypto miner. How can I confirm whenever it's is or not? If it is, how do I remove it?

Comment: Create a new Firefox Profile. Also if no Firefox process is running but you're seeing network traffic for it something is wrong. The addresses you're seeing are likely IPv6 addresses an example for Facebook would be `2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c:0:1`.

Comment: Ok What do You mean by Create a New Firefox Profile, And what should I do with the old one, how does this work?

Comment: By the way, Our Router does not support IPv6, so it's even More Strange, That there are showing up that IPv6 adresses

Comment: [Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) - it's up to you to decide what to do with the old profile. I'd first check whenever creating and using a new profile helps. How old is your router? Are you sure? What is the actual address you're seeing?

Comment: According to the German Website https://www.wieistmeineip.de/ipv6-test/ That Tells, telling me, IPv6 Adress: Not Available

Comment: Our Router model Is Fritz!Box 7560

Comment: You might be using IPv6 internally [on that model](https://avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7560/wissensdatenbank/publication/show/573_IPv6-Unterstuetzung-in-FRITZ-Box-einrichten/).

Comment: Seems Working, Whatever it was, Now CPU says, 3% Usage RAM is only 2GB (Before 3.35 GB) Network tab is Almost empty (No Firefox Process at all, Before that change about 20 - 40 Processes Firefox.exe

Comment: Profile change Seems to be working I'll try out a Benchmark test to go 4 Sure, If it will be an obviously Much better result than yesterday I'll Close The question

Answer (score -1):

pretty sure firefox stops such programs from running in tracking protection.. unless you have unticked the box in those settings. If a cpu miner has indeed been running then you must have granted it access at somepoint otherwise it would not get past firefox and your firewall

check your firewall for what apps you have granted permission recently. clear cookies in firefox and go through all security options and tailor to your needs.

Most firewalls have a purge option, comodo for example. should get rid of it.

I recommend you install "https everywhere" and "noscript". these are the only 2 tools you need to stop such things without need for firewall or firefox settings. the cpu miners cant get past noscript at all. you can test this on thepiratebay.org ;)